# AWS Serverless.yml example of WebACL config

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy lambda functions using serverless, and every time I redeploy I have to re-enable my WAF manually. How can I enable the WAF in my serverless.yml, for the API Gateway? I found [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-waf-webacl.html) but it used CloudFront, not the ApiGateway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [serverless/issues/5452](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/5452), serverless does not support this natively.

Until it does, you can allegedly use the [serverless-associate-waf](https://github.com/MikeSouza/serverless-associate-waf) plugin.

Comment: That would definitely explain why I can't find it. Thanks!

Comment: @jarmod: How about when using cloudfront with s3 to serve static website? serverless-associate-waf doesn't help in that case

Comment: @SKhurana not sure what your question is but here's a blog post on [Static Websites On AWS S3 With Serverless Framework](https://www.serverlessops.io/blog/static-websites-on-aws-s3-with-serverless-framework). If you have a follow-up question, I'd suggest cresting a new StackOverflow question with more details.